# Powershell Run Multiple vba scripts in excel workbook across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, powershell, worksheet, vba

Hi I need to run different vba scripts on different worksheets in the same workbook. Basically, each worksheet has it's own vba script which triggers an ODBC connection then updates the worksheet from a database. I've been able to get one vba script to run on one sheet and save as... no problem, but can't get anymore than one to run. here's the code I'm using

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test\Daily_update.xlsm
$Date = (Get-Date -Format dd-MM-yy)
Foreach($file in $excelFiles)
{
 $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($file.fullname)
 $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(2)
 $excel.Run("Test_Refresh")

 $workbook.saveAs("C:\test\Daily_update_$Date.xlsm")
 $workbook.close()
}
$excel.quit()
```

When I try to add other worksheets and vba scripts it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Based on the information here (http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/01/13/how-do-i-run-an-office-excel-macro-on-multiple-workbooks.aspx), that should work.  You probably need to provide us with more info: what error are you seeing?  At what point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after walking away from the problem for a little while, a little more coffee and applying some logic. I got the thing to work. So just in case you need a script to do what I was after and run a specific macro on a specific worksheet in the same workbook, here it is.

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test\Daily_update.xlsm
$Date = (Get-Date -Format dd-MM-yy)

 $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($excelfiles.fullname)
 $WS2 = $workbook.worksheets.item(2)
 $WS2.Activate()
 $excel.Run("Test_Refresh")

 $WS3 = $workbook.worksheets.item(3)
 $WS3.Activate()
 $excel.Run("test_Refresh_2")

 $WS4 = $workbook.worksheets.item(4)
 $WS4.Activate()
 $excel.Run("test_Refresh_3")

 $workbook.saveas("C:\Test\SQL\Daily_update_$Date.xlsm")
 $workbook.close()

$excel.quit()
```

Just to add a little more to this. After some trial and error I found that the following code was far more efficient at running than the above. Also I noticed that if there were only 3 worksheets it was fine but any more started to raise errors, especially when calling sheets. But this problem disappeared when the workbook was opened and visible.

```
#Call the application
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
#Now we select the file and path 
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\Server\Test\Daily_refresh.xlsm"
#The next variable speeds the script up by not calling the comobject as often
$app = $excel.Application
#Get system date and time and format it to comply with the final filename format
$Date = (Get-Date -Format dd-MM-yy)
#And again for the year folder
$Year = (Get-Date -Format yyyy)
#Test if folder exists
$DestYearFolder = "\\Server\Test\Daily_Refresh_Output\Test\$Year"
if (!(Test-Path -path $DestYearFolder)) {New-Item $DestYearFolder -Type Directory}
#Same as above only for the month folder
$Month = (Get-Date -Format MMM)
#Test if folder exists
$DestMonthFolder = "\\Server\Test\Daily_Refresh_Output\Test\$Year\$Month"
if (!(Test-Path -path $DestMonthFolder)) {New-Item $DestMonthFolder -Type Directory}
#Now we open the Excel file and activate the macro enabled content
 $workbook = $app.workbooks.open($excelfiles)
 #The next command makes Excel visible
 $app.Visible = $true
 $workbook.Activate()
 #Now we run all the Macros that need to be run.
 $app.Run("Macro_1")
 $app.Run("Macro_2")
 $app.Run("Macro_3")
 $app.Run("Macro_4")
 $app.Run("Macro_5")
 $app.Run("Macro_6")
 $app.Run("Macro_7")
 $app.Run("Macro_8")
 $app.Run("Macro_9")
 $app.Run("Macro_10")

 #Now we save the workbook in the standard daily format and the close Excel
 $workbook.saveas("\\Server\Test\Daily_Refresh_Output\Test\$Year\$Month\Daily_Refresh_test_$Date.xlsm")
 $workbook.close()

$excel.quit()
```

Comment: BTW if you want to you can actually use the spreadsheets name/label when you call it. "$ws1=$workbook.worksheets.item("Sheet1")" just easier than counting when you have a lot of them.

Comment: sometimes saving xlsm can be an issue and you might get warninging like file cannot be saved with this extension, to overcome that remove the extension from file name and specify the file type as second parameter eg: $workbook.saveas($indexTemplate,52) , here 52 is file type for macro enabled i.e xlsm